# Sort an array without rewriting a key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array which looks like this:

```
$arr = ( [0]=>Int(2)
         [1]=>Array( ....)
         [2]=>Array( ....)
         [3]=>Array( ....))
```

I have used usort to sort it:

```
usort($arr,function($a, $b) {
if($a['prop'] == $b['prop']) return 0;
    return ($a['prop'] < $b['prop']) ? 1 : -1;
});
```

My problem is that the key [0] is rewritten with an Array element. Don't get me wrong...it's suppose to. How could i sort the $arr array without rewrite the key [0] ?

Comment: the php man pages for functions have "see also" sections for most functions. It's generally HIGHLY relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use uasort()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php